# iOS UITableViewCellEditingStyle set check (ON) programatically

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When I click on Edit button in my screen i change my TableView to edit mode and set the edit style as check box by doing this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
    }
```

[image: And it looks like this]

now I need programatically pre check some of the entries.
How can i Make some of the cells as checked?

I know in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

I have to set the edit style which marks it as checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
Setting the Checkbox in an table view is equivalent to selecting the cell.
so all you need to do is mark the sell as selected, nothing to do with the Edit style

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.setup(item: item)
    cell.setSelected(true, animated: true) // Provided your cell is already in check box edit mode, then this makes it CHECK ON 
    return cell

}
```

Comment: this is creating problem . When I scroll UiTableView other cells are also selected

Answer (score 2):

By the way. I saw an explanation in similar question here (on SO) that you should not use this:

```
return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
```

Because it's not public API and if Apple changes this value, application will stop working properly. The same behaviour can be reached simply by enabling Multiple selection during editing:
[image]

You can check it easily by setting breakpoint on your overridden method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
    }
```

And enable editing during running the app with Multiple selection during editing and without it. You will see that if Multiple selection during editing is enabled, this method will not be called at all.